# reordering categories- SQL case

Tags: sql, pandas

I've run the following query on SQL to obtain the required output (attached). However, the categories are not in ascending order. I'd like to plot this in pandas and was wondering whether it would be best to reorder in SQL or pandas? Reordering in SQL seems to make sense as then I can use the following method to plot in pandas. Still relatively new to using SQL and wondering if there's something I haven't spotted here. Thanks in advance!

```
df = pd.read_csv("output/loan-cat.csv")
df.plot(x=df.index, y=df.columns)
plt.ylabel('No of loans')
plt.xlabel('Loan amount')
plt.title('No of loans, by amount')
```

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN l.loan_amnt < 5000 THEN
    '0 to 5000'
    WHEN l.loan_amnt BETWEEN 5000
    AND 15000 THEN
    '5000 to 15000'
    WHEN l.loan_amnt BETWEEN 15000
    AND 25000 THEN
    '15000 to 25000'
ELSE
    '25000 and above'
END AS " loan amount",
count(*) AS "total"
FROM
  loan AS l
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY 1 asc
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/365u0.png);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by the result from the CASE I believe you need to use a simple alias that is not a string

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN l.loan_amnt < 5000 THEN '0 to 5000'
     WHEN l.loan_amnt BETWEEN 5000 AND 15000 THEN '5000 to 15000'
     WHEN l.loan_amnt BETWEEN 15000 AND 25000 THEN '15000 to 25000'
ELSE
    '25000 and above'
END AS loan_amount,
count(*) AS "total"
FROM loan AS l
GROUP BY loan_amount
ORDER BY loan_amount asc
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. But I've. But I'm stuck with changing it in pandas. I've done:     
    lf = pd.read_csv("output/loan-cat.csv")
   lf["loan_amount"].replace({1: 'under $5000', 2: '$5000-$15000', 3: '$15000-$25000', 
    4: '$25000 and above'})  but this does not seem to replace the column. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: @Maniesha I thought this was an Sql question. I don't know anything about pandas